# Split the column and attach the new column to the table separately

Tags: bash

I have a table called baitmap.txt. In $5, different gene names are separated by ",".

**baitmap.txt**

```
1   831895  848168  218 RP11-54O7.1-001
1   848169  850618  219 RP11-54O7.2-001
1   850619  874081  220 SAMD11-011,SAMD11-003,SAMD11-010,SAMD11-001,SAMD11-004
1   889424  903640  223 NOC2L-001
1   903641  927394  224 C1orf170-001,C1orf170-201
1   927395  936954  225 HES4-002,HES4-001,HES4-004
1   943677  957199  228 RP11-54O7.11-001
1   1005127 1034268 234 RNF223-201
1   1049052 1062659 239 C1orf159-002,C1orf159-001,C1orf159-004,C1orf159-009,C1orf159-011,C1orf159-017,C1orf159-016,C1orf159-203,C1orf159-201,C1orf159-204,C1orf159-202
1   1096739 1107115 246 MIR200B-201
```

I would like to split the names in $5 then merge the new column to the previous 4 columns separately. So it should look like this:

```
1   831895  848168  218 RP11-54O7.1-001
1   848169  850618  219 RP11-54O7.2-001
1   850619  874081  220 SAMD11-011
1   850619  874081  220 SAMD11-003
1   850619  874081  220 SAMD11-010
1   850619  874081  220 SAMD11-001
1   850619  874081  220 SAMD11-004
1   889424  903640  223 NOC2L-001
1   903641  927394  224 C1orf170-001
1   903641  927394  224 C1orf170-201
```

Comment: Interesting problem.   Have you started?  Do you have any code to show?

Comment: Ah, normalization. You might appreciate a relational database, since you can probably freely choose your language, given that you have posted no c code.

Comment: I would consider C a poor language choice for this problem.   Does it need to be in C? Would you consider a more string-oriented language like Python? I think even a DOS Batch file could do this well.

Comment: Hi, no it doesn't have to be in C. Sorry I am fairly new to bioinformatics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
awk '{split($5, a, ","); $5=""; for( k in a) print $0, a[k]}' baitmap.txt
```

Note that awk hashes the array so that will permute the order.  If that matters, you can do:

```
awk '{n = split($5, a, ","); $5=""; for(k=1; k<=n; k++) print $0, a[k]}' baitmap.txt
```

Comment: @EdMorton I like that idiom for looping over the array.  I don't think I've seen that before.  Thanks!

Comment: Assigning to $5 will convert all chains of contiguous white space into single blank chars and add an extra blank before the last field on each line. To just preserve all existing white space you can do `awk '{split($5,a,/,/); sub(/[^[:space:]]+$/,""); for (i=1; i in a; i++) print $0 a[i]}' baitmap.txt` instead.

Answer (score 2):

With plain bash:

```sh
while read -ra fields; do
    # split the last field into the "values" array
    IFS=, read -ra values <<< "${fields[-1]}"
    for val in "${values[@]}"; do
        fields[-1]=$val
        echo "${fields[*]}"
    done
done < baitmap.txt
```

This requires bash v4.3+ to assign to `fields[-1]`. To work with an older bash (such as /bin/bash on a Mac):

```sh
while read -ra fields; do
    len=${#fields[@]}
    IFS=, read -ra values <<< "${fields[len-1]}"
    for val in "${values[@]}"; do
        fields[len-1]=$val
        echo "${fields[*]}"
    done
done < baitmap.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this in a few lines of BAT (Dos / Windows only)

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=1-5" %%a in (baitmap.txt) do (
    for %%i in (%%e) do (
        echo %%a %%b %%c %%d %%i
    )
)
```

### Output

```
1 831895 848168 218 RP11-54O7.1-001
1 848169 850618 219 RP11-54O7.2-001
1 850619 874081 220 SAMD11-011
1 850619 874081 220 SAMD11-003
1 850619 874081 220 SAMD11-010
1 850619 874081 220 SAMD11-001
1 850619 874081 220 SAMD11-004
1 889424 903640 223 NOC2L-001
1 903641 927394 224 C1orf170-001
1 903641 927394 224 C1orf170-201
1 927395 936954 225 HES4-002
1 927395 936954 225 HES4-001
1 927395 936954 225 HES4-004
1 943677 957199 228 RP11-54O7.11-001
1 1005127 1034268 234 RNF223-201
1 1049052 1062659 239 C1orf159-002
1 1049052 1062659 239 C1orf159-001
1 1049052 1062659 239 C1orf159-004
1 1049052 1062659 239 C1orf159-009
1 1049052 1062659 239 C1orf159-011
1 1049052 1062659 239 C1orf159-017
1 1049052 1062659 239 C1orf159-016
1 1049052 1062659 239 C1orf159-203
1 1049052 1062659 239 C1orf159-201
1 1049052 1062659 239 C1orf159-204
1 1049052 1062659 239 C1orf159-202
1 1096739 1107115 246 MIR200B-201
```

Comment: A curious choice, given the question's tags.

Comment: The original tag was C, and the poster said that C was not important.  She didn't add `bash` until after I'd created my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since this question was originally tagged `C`, it seems appropriate to do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

static void
process_line(const char *line)
{
        const char *b = line;
        int p = 1;
        for(int field = 0; *b; b++) {
                if( p && !isspace(*b) && ++field == 5 ) {
                        break;
                }
                p = isspace(*b);
        }
        int len = b - line;
        const char *s = b;
        for( ; *b; b++ ) {
                if( *b == ',' || *b == '\n' ) {
                        fwrite(line, 1, len, stdout);
                        fwrite(s, 1, b - s, stdout);
                        putchar('\n');
                        s = b + 1;
                }
        }
}

int
main(int argc, char *const argv[])
{
        (void)argc;
        (void)argv;
        char *line = NULL;
        size_t s;
        while( getline(&line, &s, stdin) != -1 ) {
                process_line(line);
        }
        free(line);
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another bash variant

```
while read line; do
    first="${line% *}"
    last="${line##* }"
    printf "$first ${last//,/\\n$first }\n"
done < baitmap.txt
```